# How to set text color of a text when a button is pressed in Java?

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement, onclicklistener

I have created programmatically, 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. Every radio button represents an answer to a question. I want when someone press the button, if the correct answer is checked, to set the color of the that text in green. What am i trying to do, is to know in the second `OnClickListener` which radio button was checked, and if it is the correct one, to make the text green. So, with this code, when i press the button, nothing happens. If i remove the condition `if (CorrectAnswer == 1)` and i press the button, i get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference`. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
boolean isChecked;
RadioButton checkedRadioButton;
RadioGroup radioButtonGroup;
int CorrectAnswer;

radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);

answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checkedRadioButton = ((RadioButton) v);
        int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());
        isChecked = true;
        if (isChecked) {
            if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked() & CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                score++;
                isChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
});

finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
            int radioGroupId = radioGroup[i].getId();
            radioButtonGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(radioGroupId);
            int checkedRadioButtonId = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
            if (CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                checkedRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say `checkedRadioButton` is `null`.

Comment: Ok, but what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Check for null ... but this will only prevent the exception. You Need to figure out, why the ID returned by getCheckedRadioButtonId is not found by findByViewId.

Comment: And how can i figure it out?

Comment: Because `radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` returns `-1` if nothing is checked.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this to avoid calling methods on a null reference.

```
if (CorrectAnswer == 1 && checkedRadioButton  != null)
```

EDIT:

Change the statement to this

```
if (checkedRadioButton  != null && Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString()) == 1)
```

Comment: Fair enough but my text is still black, not green when i press the button.

Comment: @AlexM. Where do you set CorrectAnswer?

Comment: In the first `OnClickListener`, as you see i have there `int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());`

Comment: @AlexM. So you have basically one variable for all the radiogroups. If one of those radiobuttons is checked on the wrong tag, correctanswer will be not `1` and thus the if statement will never be true. To avoid this, make either a seperate field for every radiogroup or check all radiobuttons to the correct one

Comment: This prevents calling methods on a null reference but text is still black, not green when i press the button. How can i check all radio buttons to the correct one?

Comment: Yes and still nothing happend.

Comment: @AlexM. At this point, you should start debugging the code. Look what the values of the variables are and troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm trying to do my best, but no luck so far.